# _repr_latex_ method not working anymore in Jupyter / IPython notebook

Tags: latex, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have an Expr class to represent mathematical expressions in which I defined

```
def _latex(self):
    """:return: string LaTex formula"""
    (...)
    return res

def _repr_latex_(self):
    return r'$%s$'%self._latex() #tried several variations of this...

@property
def latex(self):
    from IPython.display import Math
    return Math(self._latex())
```

as you can see on http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/Goulu/Goulib/blob/master/notebook.ipynb at cell [42], latex is correctly rendered when explicitly specified by the property
but fails next cell when called though _repr_latex_ with a UnicodeDecodeError.

e2(e1)._latex() returns '\sin(3x+2)' with no unicode, so what's wrong here ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well... it was partly my mistake : [my Expr class](https://github.com/goulu/Goulib/blob/master/Goulib/expr.py) inherits from [my Plot class](https://github.com/goulu/Goulib/blob/master/Goulib/plot.py) which has a _repr_svg_ method and Jupyter called this one by default instead of _repr_latex_ ...

Ok But:

1. the error message in Jupyter/IPython doesn't mention this
2. I still don't know how to select the default _repr_xxx_ method of a class